# Kinect library for arduino

Tags: kinect, ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a question. Because i did not find such resources on the web. Is there any way to interface kinect v2 and arduino on ubuntu 14.40 ros indigo. Can anybody provide links for it. Im trying to navigate a robot using point cloud data from kinect v2 and using that data, moving the dc motors. Can anyone guide me on this part.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257368/kinect-library-for-arduino/) by [bonzi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29118/bonzi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-03-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-03-20**:
The arduino was built to read some pins and maybe control a motor. It's by orders of magnitude too small to keep up with the data flow of a kinect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this would indeed be impossible. A Kinect2 does on average about 120MB/s, which would totally overwhelm an Arduino.

A somewhat more beefier board (RPi 2, 3 or a Jetson) will be a much better fit, although obviously more expensive.

You could then use something like `rosserial` or `ros_arduino_bridge` to use the Arduino to control your actuators.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1